# 401 Unauthorized Exception with SharePoint search rest API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, rest

**Note:** Please do not make my question as duplicate, still i haven't get any proper answer for my question.

I am getting 401 unauthorized error when calling a sharepoint search rest api (/_api/search/query?querytext) from a .net application using claims based authentication.

My request and error as below

```
httpWebRequest.Headers["X-RequestDigest"] = GetDigestForPostRequest;
 httpWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + generateClaimsIdentityToken;

 GetSearchResponse(httpWebRequest)

    private void GetSearchResponse(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (var httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                        {
                            using (var stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
                            {
                                ProcessSearchResponse(stream);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (WebException ex)
                    {//catch and log the error
                        } 



         stack trace : "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-2147024891, 
            System.UnauthorizedAccessException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"Access   
         denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access 
        this resource.\"}}}"

    [MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''.]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the spcontextinfo through rest and get the FormDigest first.

Call `http://server/web/doclib/forms/_api/contextinfo` using `POST`

Then get the `formDigestValue` from the response.

Then use that value in your headers:

```
request.Headers["X-RequestDigest"] = formDigestValue;
```

Comment: Hi Mike,I am even getting 401 unauthorized error for the below request http://mysharepointapp:203/web/doclib/forms/_api/contextinfo

Any thing wrong with my setup or access?

Answer (score 0):

using client side we can get FormDigest value

```
$.ajax({
url: "/sites/prashant/_api/contextinfo",
method: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify,
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
success: function(data, status, xhr)  
        {  
       var formdigest= data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
            console.log(data, status, xhr);  
        },  
        error: function(xhr, status, error)  
        {  
            console.log(xhr, status, error);

        }  

});
```